# Why can't I call next_back() on a Split?

Tags: rust

The documentation for [`Split`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Split.html) says that it implements [`DoubleEndedIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.DoubleEndedIterator.html) which is supposed to have a [`next_back()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.DoubleEndedIterator.html#tymethod.next_back) method which gets the last element.

But when I do this:

```rust
fn get_file_ext(file_name: &str) -> Option<String> {
    if let Some(ext) = file_name.split(".").next_back() {
        return Some(ext.to_owned());
    }
    None
}
```

I get this error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `next_back` found for struct `std::str::Split<'_, &str>` in the current scope
   --> src/lib.rs:2:45
    |
2   |       if let Some(ext) = file_name.split(".").next_back() {
    |                                               ^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `std::str::Split<'_, &str>`
    |
    = note: the method `next_back` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `std::str::pattern::StrSearcher<'_, '_>: std::str::pattern::DoubleEndedSearcher<'_>`
            which is required by `std::str::Split<'_, &str>: std::iter::DoubleEndedIterator`
```

What does it mean by `"the following trait bounds were not satisfied"`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Solution

Replace

```
file_name.split(".")
```

with

```
file_name.split('.')
```

## Explanation

Here's the trait implementation declaration:

```
impl<'a, P> DoubleEndedIterator for Split<'a, P>
where
    P: Pattern<'a>,
    <P as Pattern<'a>>::Searcher: DoubleEndedSearcher<'a>,
```

The missing trait bound here is

```
<P as Pattern<'a>>::Searcher: DoubleEndedSearcher<'a>,
```

This trait bound is implemented for the searcher of `char` but not for `&str`.

See [`DoubleEndedSearcher`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/pattern/trait.DoubleEndedSearcher.html)

> `char::Searcher` is a `DoubleEndedSearcher` because searching for a `char`
> only requires looking at one at a time, which behaves the same from
> both ends.
>
> `(&str)::Searcher` is not a `DoubleEndedSearcher` because the pattern `"aa"`
> in the haystack `"aaa"` matches as either `"[aa]a"` or `"a[aa]"`, depending
> from which side it is searched.

Said otherwise: Not all patterns allow double ended search. A `char` allows it but not a string.

Comment: Thank you! Those type annotations in the documentation make a lot more sense after reading your answer.

Comment: @Shepmaster could you point me to where I can learn more about what `<P as Pattern>` means? Are the `<>` syntactical sugar or do they have a meaning?

Comment: @financial_physician [The book covers the syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/appendix-02-operators.html). The syntax means "treat type `P` as the trait `Pattern`".